# SQL server Function - Take column name as input parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-function

I need to write a SQL function to return column specific values, so I am passing the column name as a parameter to SQL-function to return its corresponding value. Here is the sample function

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETDATETIME(@columnName VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1.@columnName  FROM TEST_TABLE ) 
END
GO
```

The above function seems to be straight forward, but it not working as expected.
And when I execute the function

```
SELECT dbo.GETDATETIME('DATETIMECOLUMNNAME')
```

I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can someone help me to identify the issue?

Comment: You can't dynamically specify the column, your query is attempting to return 'DATETIMECOLUMNNAME' which is of course not a datetime. You can't do what you want to do in a function because you need dynamic SQL which can only be run from inside an SP. And that aside its a bad design approach to be using dynamic columns. Final point you have a "." (dot) between your 1 and @columnname which isn't valid syntax either.

Comment: perhaps you need to use a dynamic query string.

Comment: @Zeina: Dynamic sql is not allowed in `sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use dynamic sql in functions in SQL. Please check this link for more info [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

So it is not possible to achieve this by any function, yes you may use stored procedures with output parameter for same.

You may find this link for reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to write dynamic sql. But Functions won't support execute statement.

So you need to write multiple If conditions for each column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETDATETIME(@columnName VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RESULT DATETIME;
    IF (@columnName = 'ABC')
    Begin
        SELECT TOP 1 @RESULT  = [ABC]  FROM TEST_TABLE
    END
    ELSE IF (@columnName = 'DEF')
    Begin
        SELECT TOP 1 @RESULT  = [DEF]  FROM TEST_TABLE
    END
    ELSE IF (@columnName = 'GHI')
    Begin
        SELECT TOP 1 @RESULT = [GHI]  FROM TEST_TABLE
    END

    RETURN  @RESULT
END
GO
```

**Edit 2:**
If your column always return Datetime, then you can do like below.

```
CREATE TABLE A_DUM (ID INT, STARTDATE DATETIME, ENDDATE DATETIME, MIDDLEDATE DATETIME)

INSERT INTO A_DUM 
SELECT 1, '2019-07-24 11:35:58.910', '2019-07-28 11:35:58.910', '2019-07-26 11:35:58.910'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2019-07-29 11:35:58.910', '2019-08-01 11:35:58.910', '2019-07-24 11:35:58.910'
```

And your function like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETDATETIME(@columnName VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @RESULT DATETIME;

SELECT TOP 1 @RESULT = CAST(PROP AS DATETIME)
FROM A_DUM
UNPIVOT
(
PROP FOR VAL IN (STARTDATE, ENDDATE,MIDDLEDATE)
)UP

WHERE VAL = @columnName

    RETURN @RESULT 
END
GO
```

Comment: giving error:  Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 508
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: This helped me in some way

Comment: Edited. Initially I didn't tested it. Thanks @DarkRob

Answer (score 2):

There's a workaround to this, similar to @Shakeer's answer - if you are attempting to GROUP BY or perform a WHERE on a column name, then you can just use a CASE statement to create a clause to match on specific column names (if you know them).

Obviously this doesn't work very well if you have many columns to hard-code, but at least it's a way to achieve the general idea.

E.g. with WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
(CASE 
  WHEN @columnname = 'FirstColumn' THEN FirstColumnCondition
  WHEN @columnname = 'SecondColumn' THEN SecondColumnCondition
  ELSE SomeOtherColumnCondition
  END)
```

Or with GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY
(CASE 
  WHEN @columnname = 'FirstColumn' THEN FirstColumnGroup
  WHEN @columnname = 'SecondColumn' THEN SecondColumnGroup
  ELSE SomeOtherColumnGroup
  END)
```